# Algebraic complement and topological complement of a subspace

Tags: linear-algebra, operator-theory

I want to know

What is difference between algebraic complement and topological complement of a subspace of a normed space $X$

Answer (score 0):

OP apparently knows what an algebraic complement is.

Googling "topological complement definition" led me to [this](http://mathonline.wikidot.com/topological-complements-of-normed-linear-subspaces), which explains that if an algebraic complement is *closed*, then it's called a "topological complement". Apparently not all subspaces have closed complements, and it's worth distinguishing those that do by giving the complements a special name. The linked page gives a nice theorem that says that a subspace of a Banach space has a topological complement if and only if a particular kind of map exists.

Comment: I want to know definition of topological complement@john hughes

Answer (score 0):

Let $U$ be a linear subspace of a Banach space $X$.

An algebraic complement of $U$ is a linear subspace $U'$ of $X$ such that $X=U \oplus U'$.

A topological complement of $U$ is a *closed* linear subspace $U'$ of $X$ such that $X=U \oplus U'$.

Comment: here U is also closed?@crostul

Comment: @ManuRohilla Not necessarily.

Comment: @Crostul I saw another definition [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1985739/why-are-topological-complements-closed). Are these two definitions equivalent? And it seems to me that in that definition both *Y* and *Z* should be closed.

Comment: I think that they are equivalent for Banach spaces, by the closed graph theorem.